# How to create multidimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy 1dimensional array with n values lets call it `xdata`.

I would like to create a multidimensional numpy array lets call it `xdataMulti` such that each dimension of this array contains values in `xdata` that are in a certain range.

For example lets say that

```
xdata = np.array([-0.879645943,-0.7897614865,-0.7051130178,-0.6108652382,-0.5270894341,...])
```

and that I want to put all values of xdata between `-0.9` and `-0.6` in  `xdataMulti[:,0]` and all values between `-0.6` and `0` in `xdataMulti[:,1]`, etc.

How do I create and fill `xdataMulti` (I know beforehand how many ranges I have and their endpoints but I dont know how many points of xdata are in each range, I have to loop through `xdata` to find out)?

Comment: That's not really what numpy (multi-)dimensional arrays are meant for! The length of the entries in each dimension should be the same.

Comment: You are describing a list of arrays of varying sizes.

Comment: Yes it is a list of arrays of varying sizes. I need each to be a numpy array in order to call a scipy function that only accepts numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your number of ranges is not too large you can create them by hand

```
 gm09 = xdata >= -0.9
 gm06 = xdata >= -0.6
 g0   = xdata >= 0
 ranges = [xdata[gm09 & ~gm06], xdata[gm06 & ~g0]]
 result = [f(r) for r in ranges]
```

where f is your scipy function.

If your number of ranges is large, you can sort your data and then use
`searchsorted`. Assuming you have the boundaries of blocks in the sorted array `bnd`:

```
xs = np.sort(xdata)
xbnd = np.searchsorted(xs, bnd)
ranges = [xs[l:r] for l, r in zip(xbnd[:-1], xbnd[1:])]
result = [f(r) for r in ranges]
```

Note that this differs from the first solution in that your ranges will be sorted.

If you need to preserve the original order you can use indirect sorting

```
order = np.argsort(xdata)
xbnd = np.searchsorted(xdata[order], bnd)
ordord = [np.sort(order[l:r]) for l, r in zip(xbnd[:-1], xbnd[1:])]
ranges = [xdata[oo] for oo in ordord]
result = [f(r) for r in ranges]
```

Comment: In the middle code *xs = np.sort(xdata)
xbnd = np.searchsorted(xs, bnd)
ranges = [xs[l:r] for l, r in zip(xbnd[:-1], xbnd[1:])]
result = [f(r) for r in ranges]* imagine xbnd is [6,18], then zip is [(6,18)] and the ranges object will only contain the range between 6 and 18 (between 0 and 6 and 18 and last are not picked).

Comment: @JennyToy Hm, isn't that how it should be? Having xbnd start at six means the smallest six values in xdata are below the smallest bin boundary, so there's no bin they should be in, at least in terms of the original Q. If you want to collect these outliers you can always do something like xbnd = np.r_[0, xbnd, len(xdata)]

Answer (score 1):

multidimensional arrays must be rectangular, so if not all of your rows/columns have the same length you're out of luck.

However there are ways to deal with this. One way would be to create a `list` of `arrays`:

```
>>> arr = np.random.random((10))  # using this for values

>>> # each item in ranges corresponds to the lower and upper border.
>>> ranges = [(0, 0.3), (0.3, 0.6), (0.6, 1)]  

>>> [arr[(arr >= lower) & (arr < upper)] for lower, upper in ranges]
[array([ 0.15346374]),
 array([ 0.38144735,  0.45017858,  0.52710788,  0.36339812]),
 array([ 0.79770651,  0.77543868,  0.94824291,  0.87412998,  0.70890894])]
```

That's not a multidimensional array, just a list of arrays, but depending on your needs that may be enough.